# How to put sheet names into combobox

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, combobox

I want to fill a combobox using the names of the excel sheets.

For example:
Sheet 1 : "Type 1"
Sheet 2 : "Type 2"
etc.

First I tried using
`Names=wb.sheet_names`

And then storing the names in an array using `Types = [Names]`

Using this array to define combobox `entry_4 = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(Parameterframe, values=Types, width=17)`

However, this puts the values next to each other and not as different options to be selected.
How can I change this code to make the sheet names as different options in the combobox?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think `Names` is already a list/tuple and don't need to put it in another list.

Comment: is `wb.sheet_names` a function or a list (or tuple)? Please provide a [mcve] in  your question.